# How to enable deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a Production function app that is set to auto deploy via Git commits.

This results in downtime so I need to enable auto swap so we can get no downtime. I'm on the standard plan but for some reason my 'Deployment Slots' options in the settings panel are grayed out so I can't select it.

I'm pretty sure they are included in my Standard plan so I'm at a bit of a loss on how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking in Azure DevOps?  Has the new slot been actually created in the portal?  AFAICT DevOps will only show you deployable slots if they already exist.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response @daniel-morritt . I actually heard back from Azure support and they said that function apps are not yet setup to use the visible 'Deployment Slots' option, which is why it's grayed out.

Function app deployment slots are actually setup via the tree navigation underneath your function app.